# Design item template with xaml

Tags: c#

I have to design a calculator like interface. 
i'm utterly confused with how to do this.can any provide me with an insight?
how to bind data with these buttons at runtime.?

Comment: Not had any experience with metro but what are you having issues with? They layout or just the bindings?

Comment: Actually both . I can't understand how to flip between to views and load content and at the same time bind the same elements to a list which has a sequential order of numbers .

Comment: Well like I said I've not touched Metro yet, I have plenty of experience with XAML though - since you are defining a distinct layout, don't you just want to use a grid to lay the buttons out and then bind to the Command property on each button (assuming this exists in metro)? There is an interface in WPF called ICommand, I'm assuming this is there too

Comment: Are you using a MVVM design?  If you are this shouldn't be that difficult.  You would create a PageViewModel and then the prev and next could move between a list of them (assuming that your prev and next move the pages).

Comment: If you linq filtered your base list and added an 'offset' or 'page' property which updated the filtered list property (make it a observable collection for change notification maybe?) you should be able to bind the control to this. Remember you can actually do indexed binding DataContext="{Binding SomeItem[1]}" so you can bind to an offset within the paged list

Comment: Gonna give this a try actually since I'm on lunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok got this working - basically I created the following XAML layout and with the following bindings:

```
<Grid x:Name="grdItems">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Content="{Binding Items[0].ItemName}"></Button>
        <Button Content="{Binding Items[1].ItemName}" Grid.Column="1"></Button>
        <Button Content="{Binding Items[2].ItemName}" Grid.Column="2"></Button>
        <Button Content="{Binding Items[3].ItemName}" Grid.Row="1"></Button>
        <Button Content="{Binding Items[4].ItemName}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"></Button>
        <Button Content="{Binding Items[5].ItemName}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"></Button>
        <Button Content="{Binding Items[6].ItemName}" Grid.Row="2"></Button>
        <Button Content="{Binding Items[7].ItemName}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"></Button>
        <Button Content="{Binding Items[8].ItemName}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"></Button>
        <Button Content="Prev" Command="{Binding MovePrevCommand}" Grid.Row="3"></Button>
        <Button Content="{Binding Items[9].ItemName}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"></Button>
        <Button Content="Next" Command="{Binding MoveNextCommand}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2"></Button>
    </Grid>
```

This gives you the grid layout

Then I created a collection manager class that would do the 'windowed view'

```
class TestCollection
{
    public ObservableCollection<TestItem> Items { get; set; }

    List<TestItem> _items = new List<TestItem>();
    int pos = 0;

    public TestCollection(int size)
    {
        MoveNextCommand = new Command(new Action(MoveNext));
        MovePrevCommand = new Command(new Action(MovePrev));


        Items = new ObservableCollection<TestItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            _items.Add(new TestItem("Item " + i.ToString()));
        }

        UpdateItems();
    }

    public void MoveNext()
    {
        pos += 10;

        if (pos > _items.Count - 10)
            pos = _items.Count - 10;

        UpdateItems();
    }

    public ICommand MoveNextCommand { get; set; }
    public ICommand MovePrevCommand { get; set; }

    public void MovePrev()
    {
        pos -= 10;

        if (pos < 0)
            pos = 0;

        UpdateItems();
    }

    private void UpdateItems()
    {
        Items.Clear();

        foreach (var i in _items.Skip(pos).Take(10))
        {
            Items.Add(i);
        }

   }

}
```

I created a simple implementation of ICommand to call a delegate:

```
class Command : ICommand
{
    Action CallBack = null;

    public Command(Action cb)
    {
        CallBack = cb;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        CallBack();
    }
}
```

TestItem is just a simple class with an ItemName property

```
class TestItem
{
    public string ItemName { get; set; }

    public TestItem(string itemName)
    {
        ItemName = itemName;
    }
}
```

Then in the main app code I added

```
 var i = new TestCollection(2000);

 grdItems.DataContext = i;
```

To wire the collection up to the grid. Works pretty well - you can add command bindings to your items to get the desired effect if you push the buttons (assuming you need buttons for each item of course!)

Let me know if that helps you get started or if there is anything you don't understand (or if this even works on Metro!!)

**Edit:** Just reading up and it seems IObservableVector now replaces ObservableCollection in WinRT

This was Jan 2012 so it may be that since then updates have added an implementation of ObservableVector - but from this article it seems you need to implement it

http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2012/01/03/Hello-ObservableVector-goodbye-ObservableCollection.aspx

Code is there anyway so no brain power required!

Comment: Oh my god Charleh!Thanks so much , i will try this and get it working.
Can't thank you enough !:)

Comment: Let me know how it goes - if you have trouble I can send you my project, but it's a WPF one so watch out for any Metro changes :)

Comment: No probs, let me know if you have any more issues